# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I am getting following error in tomcat7

error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found
        at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.listBindings(BaseDirContext.java:733)
        at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.listBindings(ProxyDirContext.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I am accessing content (classes and jsp file) by following entry inside server.xml file

```
<Host name="test" debug="0" appBase="path where classes and WEB-INF resides"
                unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="false">

                <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger"
                    prefix="om_log." suffix=".log"
                    timestamp="true"/>

        <Context path="" docBase="path where classes and WEB-INF resides" debug="0"
               reloadable="false" crossContext="false" />
       </Host>
```

Comment: I have made search for the same but not getting any satisfactory reason of error.

Comment: What is the possible reason for this error ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the structure of a web application as

TestApp
      -> WebContent
                 -> WEB-INF
you may set docBase as shown below.

```
<Context path="/TestApp" docBase="C:/project/TestApp/webapp" debug="0"
           reloadable="false" crossContext="false" />

appBase="webapps"
```

The error arises when docBase is set to the context name only.

```
docBase="C:/project/TestApp"
```

Answer (score 0):

That means that your `.war` file (in its zipped form) does not contain a directory `WEB-INF` which is meant to provide meta-data for the web-app such as e.g. `web.xml` . Or the `classes` directory within `WEB-INF` which holds the executable classes of your web-app (e.g. servlet code).

The directory name "WEB-INF" needs to be all uppercase. If you are on Windows, it may be that you have typed it in lower case, but windows zip utility shows it in upper case)

Comment: I am accessing war contents by making entry into server.xml under <host> tag and it works fine in tomcat5.

Comment: Now it looks like it may be an issue with order of initialization. So that <Host> is initialized before the war can be accessed. Just a guess.